# Angularjs - preload with percentage when route changes

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, preloading

I'm working with angularjs and to switch between pages use "ngRoute".

Before loading the new page I want to show a preload with the percentage.

How can I do?

Online not been able to find almost anything , there is some reference that I can see or tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the `$routeChangeStart` event could be what you need. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route